# Upgrade Third Party Library with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, core-plot, cocoapods

I have a project in which I am using coreplot 1.0 for graphing. (This sets the Header search path.)

How can I manage the same code with new a version of coreplot under Cocoapods? I deleted the old version, cleared the header search path etc. But after adding the new version in my project I am getting an error.

I am using following commands:

```
touch Podfile
edit Podfile # ( IOS version , Coreplot 1.4 version)
pod install
```

When I open the project workstation and try a build, I get an error.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You can either install CorePlot via CocoaPods or the manual way [here](http://victor.github.io/Core-Plot-tutorial/).

Choose one.